# Viola jones face detection...how to use tilted features from open-cv haar cascades

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, viola-jones

I am trying to understand the [**VIOLA JONES**](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf) algorithm and I came across an [implementation in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29437-viola-jones-object-detection) which uses the **open-cv haarcascade**.

It worked well for face detection (using **haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml**), but when used with other classifiers (e.g **haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml**) it gives the following warning:

```
Warning: Tilted features are not supported 
> In GetHaarCasade at 35
  In ObjectDetection at 37
```

Is there a way to also include the tilted features in the open-cv haarcascade.

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: Is there any implementation of the Viola Jones algorithm in Matlab that can detect the face features (eyes, nose, mouth). I cant use the Computer Vision Toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Viola-Jones algorithm doesn't support rotated faces because the Haar wavelets / matrices, which the algorithm is based upon, are not rotation invariant.

MATLAB has implemented a rotation invariant face detector using the KLT feature point detection algorithm instead.  If you have the Computer Vision toolbox, then check this link out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html

Comment: Thank you @rayryeng!! The problem is that I am restricted to matlab 2010 for an academic project. So is there any way to detect the face and its features(nose, eye, mouth) using the viola jones method in matlab 2010.

Comment: You'd have to incorporate rotation invariance yourself. I know of some papers that talk about it. Give me a while.

Comment: @AmitRaj - Try this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.219.5028